# .htaccess forbid for all except when specific {querystring}/$_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Foreword: I know this is a bit of a security flaw, but I'd like an htaccess solution

I have a semi-private wiki (php,mysql,mediawiki) that I'd like to allow only to a specific range of IPs, except make it public (allow all) if the article title is **title=public_articleName####** which I believe is **^title=public_articleName([0-9]{4})$** ?

I also use rewrite rules in toplevel htaccess so that the urls are beautified (`www.site.com/wiki/article` is actually `www.site.com/wiki/index.php?title=article`) in my case  I would like `www.site.com/wiki/` to be (partly) forbidden, but `www.site.com/wiki/public_articleName2345` visible for all)

Any ideas ? I know you can access %{QUERY_STRING}, but I have no idea to force a 403 based on that match (except for IPs xxx.xxx.xx.xxx)

Thanks for your input

edit:clarifications

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[forbidden]` flag on RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule  index.php?title=disallow  forbid.html  [F]
```

You can combine that with a `RewriteCond` maybe to match IPs or prevent this rule to apply to allowed pages.

```
RewriteCond  ${REMOTE_ADDR}  !78.22.131.219
RewriteRule  index.php?title=disallow  forbid.html  [F]
```

Some notes here: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask

It would however be heaps easier to implement this programmatically in the wiki software.